# Сортировка массива в Javascript ноль в конец

Tags: массивы, javascript

Есть массив

```
ar = [1,4,5,7,3,6,2,0,9,0,10,0,0]
```

Сортируем его

```
ar.sort(function(a,b){ 
 return a-b;   
})
```

Получаем 0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10

Вопрос: как отсортировать массив, чтобы на выходите получить 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,0,0,0,0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так:

```
function(a,b){
  return a*b==0?b-a:a-b;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает как нужно